# Remover ação no window.location

Tags: javascript

Estou criando uma comparação que irá fazer o seguinte, se o endereço for www.google.com irá executar a função caso contrario irá remover. Estou com este script mas não estou conseguindo montar o else.

```
if (window.location.host == 'http://www.google.com.br') {
    var optinBtn = document.querySelector('#newsletterButtonOK'),
        clickFnc = document.querySelector('#newsletterButtonOK').onclick;

    window.optinHandler = function () {
        Bat.cookie.set('allin-optin', document.querySelector('#newsletterClientEmail').value, 60);
        clickFnc();
    };

    optinBtn.setAttribute('onclick', 'window.optinHandler()');
} 
else {

}
```

Comment: Remover o que? é melhor você usar um `.match(REGEX)` do que uma simples comparação `==` que vai validar apenas 1 possibilidade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar um método do "History"

```
window.history.pushState(window.location.host, "Titulo", "/NovaUrl");
```

Esse método substituirá a URL.

Confira a [documentação](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/history.html#history-0).

Comment: Se a resposta serviu, dê um ok aí...